# Allow firefox to load insecure <form> with <input:password>

Tags: html, firefox, web

I'm on Firefox 43.0.4 and I'm no longer able to load `<form>`s that have a password field served over `HTTP`. This is a great security feature, unless I'm writing the application myself and am loading that `<form>` on `localhost`.

How can I disable this "feature" so I can continue developing my application?

I could not find any setting in `about:config` that would white list or disable this altogether.

**Error message** (displayed in developer console)

```
Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.[Learn More] <unknown>

Password fields present in a form with an insecure (http://) form action. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.[Learn More]
```